# Display error when value added in input field is not int value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running simple program in python. I am using input method and using following code

```
overflow = int(input("Enter the number"))
print(overflow)
```

I wanna that if someone will enter sting in input then input will show `please enter number only`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to put a [*`try-except` block*](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except) and [*learn about exception handling*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

```
try:
    overflow = int(input("Enter the number"))
    print(overflow)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter numbers only.")
```

`try-except` blocks are pretty cool, in the sense that you *force* an error, then *catch* it (that's what the `except` block does).

`ValueError` exceptions will be...

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the
>   right type but an inappropriate value

You can wrap this around a `while` block to prevent the code from automatically closing or carrying on.

Comment: Don't `except` everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you want

```
overflow = input("Enter the number")
try:
    overflow = int(overflow)
    print(overflow)
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter number only")
```